# Problem display only posts with comments

Tags: comments

I'm trying to make a page that will show only the posts that have comments. I have this in my page template:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts( 'cat=-8378, -13444&orderby=comment_count&paged=' . $paged );
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
```

But it's not working. It still just shows my normal post display. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: To show code from something like a page template please use pastebin or another code pasting service.

Comment: @RachelBaker A question should be understandable without any external resource.

Comment: @tosco When I first viewed the post the code snippet was not there at all.  I assumed he was pasting in the entire page template.

Answer (score 0):

your query doesn't restrict posts without comments.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    query_posts( 'cat=-8378, -13444&orderby=comment_count&paged=' . $paged );
    while (have_posts()) : 
      if(  get_comments_number() ) the_post();

   [...]
```

reference:  [get_comments_number()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_comments_number)

Comment: Um...okay, so how can I get it to restrict posts without comments?

Comment: just like in the code i showed you. relevant code: `if(  get_comments_number() ) the_post();`

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, stupid me. I misread that code as simply a quote of mine. Thanks, I'll give it a try!